# Cannot ingest the data in AWS Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

How to ingest data in aws elasticsearch (public access/no encryption). I have already tried using "curl" and Postman but it shows me error.

Comment: can you add curl and the error response you are getting?

Comment: @BaluVyamajala Hey Balu, thank you for your concern. I have found out the issue. Thanks alot.